# Prevent from opening Excel sheet ridden with OLEDB Connection

Tags: vba, excel, oledbconnection

I am currently using OLEDB connection to import/data in excel workbook from an another workbook which is running on another computer. 
The connection mode I use is 'adModeRead'. So far it worked well but since a few days I have been facing an issue :

Eachtime I launch the import/update of the data it opens on my computer the data source excel workbook in read only mode. 
Do you know how I can prevent from opening the data source file on my computer? (I just want to import the data without open the excel file)

Here under my code:

```
Public Sub GetExistingData()
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim texte_SQL As String
Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

'--- Connection ---
With Cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
        & Folder & "\" MyDataSource.xlsm";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
    .Mode = adModeRead
    .Open
End With


texte_SQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & dataSheetName & "$]"

Set Rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set Rst = Cn.Execute(texte_SQL)
```

Comment: Give `Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES;Mode=Read;ReadOnly=True;` in your connection string a shot.

Comment: I've just tried and it doesn't resolve the issue... My datasource xlsm excel file still opens as read only in a new instance of excel when I launch the connection....

Comment: *off-topic* : why do you need to have two different providers?

Comment: Any additional idea?

Comment: Ash, i just import data from an another Excel Workook which compute data on a réal Time basis